# Tkinter refresh problem with label picturre and serial timeout after 1 minutes

Tags: python, image, tkinter, timeout, label

I am trying to get serial data array from arduino and use them as a coordinates for labels with Python3 in my Raspberry Pi 3. I can get the arrays with serial and put the labels as i want. Program works. But
First problem is i can see flicker and delay time for flicker is getting worst with time.
Second problem is program stop working after a few minutes.

I tried ser.flushInput() and i cleared my arrays every where and the result is the same.

```
from tkinter import *
import serial
root = Tk()
root.geometry("1024x600")
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyAMA0',115200)
ser.timeout=None

data=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
data1=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
image=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
label=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
x1=[210,210,210,370,370,370,530,530,530,690,690,690,850,850,850,850]
y1=[440,325,75,440,325,75,440,325,75,440,325,75,440,325,200,75]

image_gri=PhotoImage(file="/home/pi/python/gri.gif")
image_kirmizi = PhotoImage(file="/home/pi/python/kirmizi.gif")
image_yesil = PhotoImage(file="/home/pi/python/yesil.gif")

def kontrol():
 data=[]
 ser.flush()
 ser.flushInput()
 data = ser.read(32)
 #print(data)

 for i in range(0,16):
      if data[i]==49 and data[i+16]==49:

            image[i]=image_yesil
            label[i] = Label(root, image=image[i])
            label[i].place(x=x1[i],y=y1[i])


      elif data[i]==49 and data[i+16]==48:
            image[i]=image_kirmizi
            label[i] = Label(root, image=image[i])
            label[i].place(x=x1[i],y=y1[i])

      else :
            image[i]=image_gri
            label[i] = Label(root, image=image[i])
            label[i].place(x=x1[i],y=y1[i])


 ser.flush()
 ser.flushInput()               
 root.after(50,kontrol)
 root.update()
kontrol()
#root.after(50,kontrol)
mainloop()
```

I want the program works for up to 12 hours and see no flicker when it is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are adding 16 Label widgets in every run, which are kept in memory and processed each time. The old Labels are never removed.

To solve this, you could delete the previous label when you create a new one, using `label[i].destroy()`. Even better is to just update the existing label instead of creating a new label, using `label[i].config(image=...)`.

Below is a fully working example (with some code commented out, and using random data and dummy images instead, so anyone using Python 3 can run this without external dependencies):

```
import random
from tkinter import *
# import serial

root = Tk()
root.geometry("1024x600")
# ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyAMA0', 115200)
# ser.timeout = None

# If you have the images, use this:
#IMAGE_GRI = PhotoImage(file="/home/pi/python/gri.gif")
#IMAGE_KIRMIZI = PhotoImage(file="/home/pi/python/kirmizi.gif")
#IMAGE_YESIL = PhotoImage(file="/home/pi/python/yesil.gif")

# Otherwise, create some dummy images for demonstration purposes:
WIDTH = 64
HEIGHT = 64
DATA = ','.join(['0x00' for i in range(WIDTH * HEIGHT // 8)])
BITMAP = '#define im_width %d\n#define im_height %d\nstatic char im_bits[] = {\n%s\n};' % (WIDTH, HEIGHT, DATA)
IMAGE_GRI = BitmapImage(data=BITMAP, background="grey")
IMAGE_KIRMIZI = BitmapImage(data=BITMAP, background="red")
IMAGE_YESIL = BitmapImage(data=BITMAP, background="green")

# Initialize with grey images (you may choose a different image, of course)
label = [Label(root, image=IMAGE_GRI) for i in range(16)]

x1 = [210, 210, 210, 370, 370, 370, 530, 530, 530, 690, 690, 690, 850, 850, 850, 850]
y1 = [440, 325, 75, 440, 325, 75, 440, 325, 75, 440, 325, 75, 440, 325, 200, 75]

# Place the images only once:
for i in range(16):
    label[i].place(x=x1[i], y=y1[i])

def kontrol():
    data = []
    # ser.flush()
    # ser.flushInput()
    # data = ser.read(32)
    # Create random data for demonstration purposes:
    data = [random.choice((48, 49)) for i in range(32)]
    #print(data)

    for i in range(16):
        if data[i] == 49 and data[i+16] == 49:
            label[i].config(image=IMAGE_YESIL)  # update image!
        elif data[i] == 49 and data[i+16] == 48:
            label[i].config(image=IMAGE_KIRMIZI)  # update image!
        else:
            label[i].config(image=IMAGE_GRI)  # update image!

    # ser.flush()
    # ser.flushInput()
    root.after(50, kontrol)
    # root.update()  # Not necessary! Use root.update_idletasks() if necessary.

kontrol()
mainloop()
```

Comment: Really thanks for your reply. Your codes are works very well. I am new in python programming. I can guess the problem but i cant apply in python. :) You saved my all weeks thanks again.